# Using Find/Replace in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-pro

With my company switching to ArcGIS Pro, I am having to relearn some stuff that I've always known to work. In Pro I accidentally added "ft" to every column rather than just one.

Is there a way to get rid of the "ft" within each column?

Attached is the picture of my issue.

[image]

Comment: That's interesting...out of curiosity, how did you do that? You could write a python script to fix it, but by the time you did that you could have probably just used calculate field manually on each field, with an expression like `!field![:-3]`.

Comment: I imported the data from ArcMap, so that's why I currently have the "ft" in all of the columns - I accidentally added it in ArcMap and found out after bringing it into Pro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the .replace() function with python.

Right click your field, field calculator, !FIELDNAME!.replace('ft',''), that will replace all instances of ft with a blank, wherever it is in your field

Comment: Is there any chance you could do a pretend set up - so I can actually understand what word/field goes where in the calculator?

Comment: !FIELDNAME!.replace('ft','')

Comment: It ended up not working - using the miniscule amount of experience I have in field calculator, I did:                 !Length!.replace("ft", " ")   This worked perfectly. Couldn't have done it without your help!

Comment: yes, replace FIELDNAME with the name of your field